# How do you define an array field when using create in mongoid?

Tags: mongoid

I'm trying to create a seed file to populate my mongo database. The following syntax creates a `nil` value when I try to define the array field value.  I'm using mongoid v3.0.9.  What am I doing wrong?

These following examples do not work when I put them in the seed file:

```
User.create(name:'name', test_array_field:'[123,123]')
User.create(name:'name', test_array_field:[123,123])
User.create(name:'name', test_array_field:[123,123].to_a)
```

I've defined the field in my class like so:

```
field :test_array_field, type: Array
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second syntax works for me.

```
class User
  field :roles, type: Array, default: []
end

u = User.create roles: ['superadmin']
u.new_record? # => false
u.roles # => ["superadmin"]
```

Comment: Can you try putting the `User.create` into a seed file and running it?

Comment: Can you do the reverse? Try it in your console?

Comment: I've already tried it in my console and it works like it works with you.  Its only when its in a seed.rb file that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :bar, :type => Array, :default => []
  field :baz, :type => Hash, :default => {}
end
```